# Understanding Mvc Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I have been trying to find an explanation, but are coming rather short, as to how exactly identity works with mvc core. I have found numerous guides on how to implement it and I have and it all works great, but I want to understand it under the hood at the very least on a high level.

My current understanding is that when a user passes their credentials, identity library will issue a token and that token will be written to the browser's cookies. Now all further requests will have the user identified based on that browser cookie. However, I can't seem to find explanations past that. Why is this safe, why can't I steal that cookie and use it as my own? I know there is more to this and potentially I have understood the above part wrong.

In any case, I'm either looking for a high-level explanation on how this works or a good reference that can delve more into details.

Comment: Have you already read the official docs?

Comment: I have, but all I can find are examples on how to implement this in your project. That is not that I am asking here.

Comment: I don't mind the down-voting, but at least explain why you are doing so. I don't think I've done anything against the rules here. I've done my research first and couldn't come up with anything, so I'm asking for help here.

Comment: Identity is best understood as an auth provider/store. It concerns itself mostly with user management: creating, updating, assigning roles and other claims, passwords, two-factor, etc. What you're actually talking about here is the ASP.NET Core authentication and authorization subsystem, specifically cookie auth. Identity merely supports that, but you could just as easily switch out Identity with something like IdentityServer, Auth0, or even an entirely custom system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how exactly identity works with mvc core.

As @[Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt) says, what you're talking about is the security subsystem. Since you're talking about cookie, I'll take the authentication scheme of cookie as an example.

The built-in security could be mainly found in 4 projects:

- [HttpAbstractions](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions): core interfaces and classes, such as authentication scheme, authentication handler, authentication ticket and so on.
- [Security](https://github.com/aspnet/Security): authentication middleware, cookie authentication, JWT Bearer authentication, OAuth2.0 authentication(Google/Facebook/Microsoft/...) and so on.
- [Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) : a scaffold project named as "Identity" that helps to manage user/roles/claims/etc.
- [DataProtection](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/DataProtection) : Data Protection APIs for protecting and unprotecting data. You can treat it as an API to encrypt and decrypt.

The entry point to understand how authentication works is the [`AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L32). This middleware will try to authenticate every request if possible:

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // ...

        // Give any IAuthenticationRequestHandler schemes a chance to handle the request
        var handlers = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationHandlerProvider>();
        foreach (var scheme in await Schemes.GetRequestHandlerSchemesAsync())
        {
            var handler = await handlers.GetHandlerAsync(context, scheme.Name) as IAuthenticationRequestHandler;
            if (handler != null && await handler.HandleRequestAsync())
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Use the default scheme to authenticate request
        var defaultAuthenticate = await Schemes.GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync();
        if (defaultAuthenticate != null)
        {
            var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(defaultAuthenticate.Name);
            if (result?.Principal != null)
            {
                context.User = result.Principal;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
```

Usually, this middleware runs before other middlewares/mvc thus you can intercept requests as you need.

When you want to access an `url` protected by `[Authorize]` without login, it will ask you to sign in through some scheme. You can configure your services to use different schemes as you like, such as Jwt Bearer, cookies, and so on.

If you're using the cookie scheme, 
[CookieAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L169) will do the heavy lifting :

- [Signin](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L253): will issue a new cookie when you think you have validated the user principal.
- [Authenticate](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L169): validate the cookie sent by client
- [Signout](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L340) : delete the cookie

**Note all these are done by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler`, i.e. a handler defined in `aspnet/Security`, not the `aspnet/Identity` library**.

> why can't I steal that cookie and use it as my own?

1. Of course you can steal someone's cookie and use it as your own. Actually, if Alice's cookie is stolen by Bob (let's say through `XSS` or `sniffering`), Bob will be treated as Alice. ASP.NET Core (and other technologies such as PHP/Python/Java) cannot prevent this and there're quite a lot to do to prevent the stealing :

   - The website should use `HTTPS` rather than `HTTP`
   - encode characters like `<`,`>`,`<img onclick='javascript:'` and so on to prevent XSS
   - ...
2. Also, you don't need to steal someone's cookie sometimes. By `CSRF`, you simply "borrow" his cookie.

> Why is this safe

Typically, even if it's possible to steal someone's cookie or borrow someone's cookie in theory, it will only happen when you're developing your app in a wrong way or deploy them in an insecure way.

Another thing is that you could hardly fake a cookie on client side.

Comment: +1 for the reference to cookies.  Are you able to answer my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179214/asp-net-identity-roles-not-honoured ?